# how does one decide shortest path in a mesh network?

Tags: networking, mesh-network

I'm currently working on a project with a friend with many nodes in a network, and would like to adapt it from p2p to a mesh network.

Some background on the application:

- we aren't doing anything complicated, we're just starting off with a chat client, sending messages to/from an individual/group(s)
- language agnostic (I'm writing my 'client' in ruby, and my friend is writing his in python)
- currently, we have a listening socket (which is always active), and only open sockets for sending, so there is no 'always-on' connection to all of our nodes (though, from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking), it seems they prefer constant connections)
- I've also read this on [scalable source routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Source_Routing), but it more or less just lays out "a" algorithm, and doesn't necessarily define any sort of protocol for communication.

So, my questions:

- What's the best (or a comparison of) mesh networking protocol(s) for finding shortest path? (I know there are a couple, defined by IEEE and others)

  - Lets say you want to send a message to someone you aren't directly connected to

    - do you have a list of all nodes on the network and lookup which of your connected nodes has the shortest path to your intended target node? -- would this mean that every time the network changes, you'd have to update each node's graph of the network?
    - alternatively, would a node just have a list of which of its connected nodes have the shortest path to a desired destination? (this way the responsibility of shortest path falls to the next-in-line node)?
- how do you decide which nearby nodes to maintain connections to?

thanks!

Comment: Define what you mean by the shortest path. Is is strictly the number of hops (Distance-Vector), or do you want to include other criteria (e.g. bandwidth)? You need to nail down exactly what you mean first.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought about that. I guess, initially, number of hops to keep things simple. Bandwidth and latency can be taken in to consideration at a later stage.

Comment: Well, those are different algorithms. A simple DV routing protocol is RIP, and you can find that algorithm easily enough. Taking other criteria into account can get complex, and there are several Link-State algorithms that you can investigate.